# How to store same data in array multiple times?

Tags: typescript, loops, dialogflow-es, array-push

I am getting an audio URL and some text from [this](http://api.alquran.cloud/v1/ayah/2:1/editions/ar.alafasy,en.asad) api. Till now I am able to get this response on dialogflow using webhook.

Now I need to get the same data multiple times. For example till now if I ask to **play the audio** it **provides url 1 time**. Now I want it to **return the URL multiple times** such as when I ask it to play the audio 2 times or 100 times it should give the url accordingly.

The URLs must be stored in an array in the same way I am doing it.

I'm pushing the object containing "url", "title" and "type" into an array named 'messages'. It should be pushed the particular no. of times I specify using 'times' variable.

This is what I have tried yet. Please check the loop if it is placed the right way? This function is fine without loop and returns data once. Let me know if any other detail is required.

**Code**

```
static readAyahOfSurahMultipleTimes = async (agent: any) => {
      

           const params = agent.parameters
           console.log("params: ", params)
  
           let surahApi: any = await http.get(`http://api.alquran.cloud/v1/ayah/${params.surahName}:${params.ayahNumber}/editions/ar.alafasy,en.asad`);
           
           var ayahs: any = surahApi["data"];  
           console.log("ayahs", ayahs);
      
           let payload = {
               "web": {     
                   "messages": []
               }
           }
           try {
               ayahs.forEach(function (item) {
                   for(var i=0;i<params.times;i++){
                   payload.web.messages.push({                              
                       "url": item.audio,
                      // "title": item.text,
                      "title": surahApi["data"][0]["text"],
                       "type": "audio",
                   }) 
                }
               });
               console.log("payload", payload);
               console.log("payload.web.messages",payload.web.messages);
      
      
               raw.response.send({
      
                   "fulfillmentText": `Ayah number ${params.ayahNumber} of surah number ${params.surahName} is being played`,   
                   "payload": payload
               })
               return;
           } catch (e) {
               console.log("error in catch block", e);
               raw.response.send({
                   "fulfillmentText": `response from catch`
               })
           }
       }
```

**FULFILLMENT RESPONSE**
[image]

Comment: Are you pushing a 'payload' object in the 'messages' array for each time the audio needs to be replayed?

Comment: I'm pushing the object containing "url", "title" and "type" into 'messages' array. It should be pushed the no. of times I specify using 'times' variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `ayahs` is an array that contains two objects, and only the first object contains the audio url (try to open http://api.alquran.cloud/v1/ayah/2:286/editions/ar.alafasy,en.asad in the browser to check a response). You are currently looping through both of these objects, and attaching the audio url of both objects to the url property of the array objects, the reason why it only worked once is because the audio url exists on the first object only.You need to eliminate the first `forEach` loop and access the audio through the first element of `ayahs` array.

```
static readAyahOfSurahMultipleTimes = async (agent: any) => {

     const params = agent.parameters

     let surahApi: any = await http.get(`http://api.alquran.cloud/v1/ayah/${params.surahName}:${params.ayahNumber}/editions/ar.alafasy,en.asad`);

     var ayahs: any = surahApi["data"];  


     let payload = {
        "web": {     
            "messages": []
        }
     }

     try {
        let ayah: any = ayahs[0];
        let audio:string = ayah.audio;

        for(var i=0; i<params.times; i++){
           payload.web.messages.push({                              
              "url": audio,
              "title": surahApi["data"][0]["text"],
              "type": "audio",
           }) 
        }          

        raw.response.send({
           "fulfillmentText": `Ayah number ${params.ayahNumber} of surah number ${params.surahName} is being played`,   
           "payload": payload
        })

        return;
     } 
     catch (e) {
       raw.response.send({
          "fulfillmentText": `response from catch`
        })
     }
  }
```

Now I think that what you're doing by replicating the data on the message array is pointless, you could simply add a property for the number of times the audio needs to be repeated in the payload object, and then configure it on the client to be repeated multiple times using this variable.

```
payload.web.messages.push({                              
   "url": audio,
   "title": surahApi["data"][0]["text"],
   "repititionTimes": params.times
   "type": "audio"
})
```

This way you won't have to use a loop and you won't send unnecessary payload.